# How to get or filter a bunch of childNodes by their style class name in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble figuring out how to get or filter a bunch of childNodes by their style class name inside my useEffect. Using ReactJs v18.

Straight after the line with: `const circleElements = launcherCircle!.childNodes;` I would like to get/filter the div's with the class name 'launcherPos' so I can position them in a circle formation.

```
const LauncherComponent = () => {
  const launcherCircleRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  let modules: Module[] | null = GetModules();

  const enableLauncher = (module: Module) => {
    return !module.IsEnabled ? styles['not-active'] : null;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const launcherCircle = launcherCircleRef.current;
    const circleElements = launcherCircle!.childNodes;
    let angle = 360 - 190;
    let dangle = 360 / circleElements.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < circleElements.length; i++) {
      let circle = circleElements[i] as HTMLElement;
      angle += dangle;
      circle.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${launcherCircle!.clientWidth / 2}px) rotate(-${angle}deg)`;
    }
  }, []);

  if (modules == null){
    return <Navigate replace to={'/noaccess'} />
  } else {
    return (
      <div data-testid="Launcher" className={styles['launcherContainer']} >
        <div className={styles['launcherCircle']} ref={launcherCircleRef}>
          {modules.map(function (module: Module, idx) {
            return (
              <div key={idx} className={styles['launcherPos']} ><div className={`${styles['launcherButton']} ${enableLauncher(module)}`}><img src={module.ImagePath} alt={module.Prefix} /></div></div>
            )
          })}
          <div className={styles['launcherTextDiv']}>
            <span>TEST</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
export default LauncherComponent;
```

From what I've read `getElementsByClassName()` is not advisable practise because of the nature of ReactJs and it's virtual DOM.

I tried the following filter but I think with React garburling the class name I didn't get anything back.

```
const launcherChildren = launcherCircle!.children;
const circleElements = [...launcherChildren].filter(element => element.classList.contains('launcherPos'));
```

Maybe there's a way to ref an array of the just the children with the launcherPos class???

There must be a couple of different ways, but, they are eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter/map an array of `HTMLElements`, the results are in the form of objects, which contains properties like, `props`, `ref` etc.
Since `className` is a prop on the element, you should try looking for the class name by digging into the `props` key.
Simply put, all the props that you pass to the element, like `onClick`, `onChange`, `value`, `className` are stored under the `props` property.
You can filter the results by converting the class name into an array and further checking if it contains the target string (`launcherPos` in this case).

Your code should look something like this:

```
const circleElements = [...launcherChildren].filter(element=>element.props.className.split(' ').includes('launcherPos'))
```

The above method could be used when an array directly holds elements. E.g: `[<div></div>,<div></div>...]`.
The approach that you've followed is correct, except for the way you are selecting the elements by their class names. I can see that you are using CSS modules in this component, meaning all the class names exist as properties on the imported object(`styles` in this case), so when you use `contains('launcherPos')` you are essentially checking for the presence of a string, but when using CSS modules, class names are available only as object properties, that's the reason you are getting an empty array. Simply update `launcherPos` to `styles.launcherPos` and that shall fix the issue.
All-in-all your `useEffect` function should look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const launcherCircle = launcherCircleRef.current;    
    
    const launcherChildren = launcherCircle!.children;    
    const circleElements = [...launcherChildren].filter(element => element.classList.contains(styles.launcherPos)); //change launcherPos to styles.launcherPos

    let angle = 360 - 190;
    let dangle = 360 / circleElements.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < circleElements.length; i++) {
      let circle = circleElements[i] as HTMLElement;
      angle += dangle;
      circle.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${launcherCircle!.clientWidth / 2}px) rotate(-${angle}deg)`;
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Sorry Prajwal, but the props property doesn't want to compile, its giving me: "Property 'props' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)" when I use launcherCircle!.children, or if I use launcherCircle!.childNodes: "Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.ts(2339)". Does that mean I need to cast element in some fashion?

Comment: Hello Hank, I've updated the answer, kindly check. This shall fix the issue.

Comment: Great thank you, everything is working as expected now